# Shopify app integration theme issue

Tags: css, shopify

I am developing application for shopify, which replace login and register links to another links, creating a custom pages. For example when user click to login link? it is not redirect to login page, it is open a popap with login form. Also my app create custom pages. For example people page, where shows list of customers. And also a want to customize product page  by adding a new fave button. In people page for each people shows count faves and last three faves product with images.

So my problems is theme layouts. Because each theme have self layout and css. I want to my app support all themes. How can i do it?

Sorry for my bad english. I just learning... ))

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here, http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies and http://docs.shopify.com/api/scripttag.

App proxy sounds like the solution for your separate 'peoples' page.

If you want to assume that all themes have a log in link (which they all should but it's completely customizable so it's possible some don't), then you could always do something like this
$("a[href='/account/login']").click(funciont() {// show modal}); This isn't guaranteed to work in all themes but it probably will in most.